# Non-consecutive numbered array .NET

Tags: c#, .net, collections

What collection type would I use in C# for an array where the indexes are non-consecutive (but are only added in ascending order), and I need access both by index and by place (e.g. "consecutive index")?

For example, if I add the objects A, B and C with indexes 2, 4 and 7, I need to access by index (2/4/7) or by place (1/2/3 or 0/1/2 both work).

Comment: Are A,B and C or 2,4 and 7 unique?

Comment: Tying together a dictionary for key lookup and a list for order is probably your best bet. I think you could probably do something using a k-d tree for this, although I don't know much about them, and I think that would be a bit overkill for this. Possibly if you want to get down and dirty it might be made a little more efficient by reimplementing parts of the Dictionary class, but I think that would be a bad idea.

Comment: @TimSchmelter In my current case they are unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `Dictionary` to store the objects for access by their index, but you'll also need some kind of `List` to store the 'place' as `Dictionary` doesn't store place. Join these together in your own class and handle adding as one operation to make sure they are in sync.

If you only want to use one, you can use the `List` and loop over it to look up the key, but it will take linear O(N) time.

**Edit**

As Matthew Strawbridge points out, the `BinarySearch` method will find the element in O(log N) so you can skip using the dictionary.

Comment: Even if just using a `List` of pairs, because it's sorted you can use [`List<T>.BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/w4e7fxsh(v=vs.110).aspx) to look up an element in O(log N) time.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Dictionary`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

Dictionary<int, type> dict = new Dictionary<int, type>();

// Add values:
dict.Add(2, A);
dict.Add(4, B);
dict.Add(7, C);

// by index:
var A = dict[2];
var B = dict[4];
var C = dict[7];

// by place:
var A = dict.ElementAt(0);
var B = dict.ElementAt(1);
var C = dict.ElementAt(2);
```

Comment: I'm not sure order of insertion is guaranteed to be order of storage with a ***Dictionary<K,T>***. The "by index" would work guaranteed, but I'm not sure about the "by place". If you want to guarantee indexed access, use the ***OrderedDictionary<K,T>*** instead.

Comment: Insertion order is certainly not guaranteed. ElementAt is a hack that works on any IEnumerable. A red flag by itself.

Comment: It still is the most viable option, excluding making a IEnumerable subclass.

Comment: @MicaelBergeron why would it be viable if it returns the wrong results? It can return any order at all.

Comment: Correct, `ElementAt()` gives the values by order of insertion, but as he said: "indexes are non-consecutive (but are only added in **ascending order**)", so for this case it is suitable

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) "For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined."

Comment: @marsze You might find that the elements do come back in the right order, but you shouldn't rely on that. It could change in a future .NET implementation.

Comment: I think given that the order is undefined, it's not safe to assume that at all. Unless there's some piece of documentation to back that up.

Comment: You are right, I deleted the comment. Still looking forward to good alternatives though.